# Oracle database startup leads to errors

Tags: linux, oracle

Used the Oracle Linux Server 8.2 and its terminal shows below errors.

> ORA-01261: Parameter db_recovery_file_dest destination string cannot be translated
> ORA-01262: Stat failed on a file destination directory
> Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory

[image: ][1]]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is literally written on your terminal. You seem to have a db_recovery_file_dest parameter set to a location that does not exist.

As with many oracle database failures, the alertlog will show the problem with a bit more detail. The alertlog will show the parameter value.

Since you don't have a question, just a remark about an error, I assume you needed some guidance as how to find the details of this error. Look in the alertlog file. To get the database started make sure that the specified location exists and is writeable by the oracle's processes.